# Rescan font list Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Is there a function in Inkscape to refresh the font list? Anytime I install a new font I have to restart Inkscape to use it.

Something like ***"Rescan font list"*** in GIMP.

Comment: Apparently, there isn't that function in inkscape.
There are two open bugs open on Inkscape's launchpad regarding this:
https://blueprints.launchpad.net/inkscape/+spec/reload-font-library-button
https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/168960

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inkscape get all font list when starts. Then problems come when you try to add new fonts if you don't use right permissions (linux OS) , bad locations (Wiondos AppData folders - from install of inkscape software) or something else.

One example: to install the *.ttf* files use right clik into explorer and use Install from menu.

If you want a script to parse all your fonts then Inkscape let you using scripting languages to create new Inkscape functionality.

Answer (score 2):

For windows - Make sure you right-click the `font.otf` files and select **"Install for All Users"**. This is why

Comment: didn't work for me , I had to restart the Inkscape